# Why SDWebImage Used LOCK on NSCache?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nscache

In [NSCache](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nscache?language=objc) document 
 Apple says

> You can add, remove, and query items in the cache from different
>   threads without having to lock the cache yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, they don't use `LOCK` on `NSCache`. [Here's](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/blob/f28796de62bc8ffd33f874c0f52578b4bcea094c/SDWebImage/SDImageCache.m) their caches implementation.

They have multiple different types of cache, and the only one which is wrapped in LOCK/UNLOCK is `weakCache`:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong, nonnull) NSMapTable<KeyType, ObjectType> *weakCache; // strong-weak cache
```

Which is an object of `NSMapTable`. `NSMapTable` is not [thread safe](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafetySummary/ThreadSafetySummary.html):

```
// `setObject:forKey:` just call this with 0 cost. Override this is enough
- (void)setObject:(id)obj forKey:(id)key cost:(NSUInteger)g {
    [super setObject:obj forKey:key cost:g];
    if (!self.config.shouldUseWeakMemoryCache) {
        return;
    }
    if (key && obj) {
        // Store weak cache
        LOCK(self.weakCacheLock);
        [self.weakCache setObject:obj forKey:key];
        UNLOCK(self.weakCacheLock);
    }
}
```